# Is SSL/TLS still needed on same machine WS calls

Tags: web-services, authentication, ssl

So, is it really necessary to configure SSL/TLS when WS calls will only happen on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That will not be necessary.

SSL/TLS assumes communication over an untrusted network (e.g. Internet).

If your communicating nodes (programs) are within a trusted network boundary (e.g. on the same machine), then sending encrypted messages between them will only waste your CPU cycles, and slow down communication.

[EDIT]

Also certificate verification will be useless and less secure if you need to leave the trusted network (localhost) to another to check with the CA who issued the certificate. The node/program you are talking to might as well issue a self-signed certificate which is like someone asking you to trust them because they believe themselves to be trustworthy :)

Read more here. [SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)